# android ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm making an android game with AndEngine. I have an arraylist of sprites, and on each update I want to check if the player sprite has collided with any of them. But this excerpt of my code is giving me a headache:

```
public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
    sprites.addAndRemove();
    for (int i=0;i<sprites.size();i++) {
        if(playerSprite.collidesWith(sprites.get(i))) {
            sprites.setToRemove(i); 
            //adds the sprite to a removal queue arraylist. 
            //the actual sprites arraylist is not touched until addAndRemove() fires.
        }
    }
}
```

Looks pretty basic, but somehow `sprites.get(i)` throws this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  883): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
E/AndroidRuntime(  883): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
```

Despite `i<sprites.size()`, i is somehow reaching the value of `sprites.size()`. I put log messages in each iteration spelling out the size of the arraylist and the current value of i, and it seems to be correct:

```
D/app(  883): size is 4
D/app(  883): i is 0
D/app(  883): size is 4
D/app(  883): i is 1
D/app(  883): size is 4
D/app(  883): i is 2
D/app(  883): size is 4
D/app(  883): i is 3
```

...followed immediately by the exception.

So I'm stumped here, how can this happen?

```
W/dalvikvm(  883): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
E/AndroidRuntime(  883): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedUpdate(Entity.java:776)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:648)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedUpdate(Entity.java:776)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedUpdate(Scene.java:261)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:648)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateScene(Engine.java:494)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:465)
E/AndroidRuntime(  883):    at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:684)
```

Comment: can you post the full for loop code, and more of the error log?

Comment: edited, i put the entire onUpdate method

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

```
for(Sprite sprite : sprites){
   if (playerSprite.collidesWith(sprite)) {
      //--
   }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
for (Iterator<Sprite> i = sprites.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
      if (playerSprite.collidesWith(i.next())) {
         //--
      }
}
```

Method 1 is more preferable.

Comment: which method you tried, try commenting entire code inside loop & just print the object sprite